# Chrome - access http queues

Tags: javascript, api, http, browser

I am having a problem with a large amount of http requests placed at the same time. Browsers are complaining about pages being unresponsive or slowing down Browser (FF). I am thinking to add some control to how many requests have been placed. Ideally, I would check the current http queue and add more requests accordingly. Is there a programmatic way of accessing http queues?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing is going to get you the active requests. Be better to know why you are making so many requests at once. Might be a better solution. And not sure how http request would make it unresponsive. Sounds like we have calls that are blocking. Again, can't help without knowing what is generating the calls.

Comment: It is a business request to provide UI that allows to pull up to 100 charts. With a single click a user can place all 100 requests at once.

Comment: Make 1 request that returns 100s of charts, if the user can possibly fit all of them on one screen.

Comment: It is a possibility, although would require compete refactoring of a data pipe. Regardless, it is a possibility, thanks.

Comment: However, it will take a long time and a user wont see anything, as now he gets one chart after another, which is much better UX.

Comment: Sounds like the code also blocks the UI. Seems like a better option is to either bulk update or queue the requests. Hard to tell without seeing code.

Comment: The code is simple. It's a loop on the front-end that places POST requests. when you say "queue the requests" what do you meant by that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment (not enough reputation). Is there any reason you can't use JSON to send a list of requests in 1 request then parse over those and compile all the individual responses into one HTTP response and then parse that on the front end. essentially put all the information you need to send into one large request and I guess you could send each response individually.

Comment: See my comment above.